# Perl uninitialized value in numeric gt?

Tags: perl, initialization

I'm a beginner in Perl and I get this message when I execute my code:

```
Use of uninitialized value $triggerCheck in numeric gt (>) at 
./advanced-daemon.pl line 101.
```

This is the only error/warning I get when executing my code. The code, itself, works without any problems but I'm wondering what's the problem in that variable?

To reproduce the problem you can use this code:

```
while(1==1)
{
   my $triggerCheck = "10";
   if($triggerCheck < 10)
   {
      print "This var is < 10";
   }
   $triggerCheck = 9;
   sleep 1;
}
```

Edit: I solved my problem. Sorry for bothering you all :)

Comment: That code is perfectly fine.  You have to show us the real code. Probably it’s because of the EvilCamelCaseVariablesThatMakePerlJealousBecauseItWantsToBeAlphaCamel. :)

Comment: Could try looking now - I did make some changes I forgot to add here :)

Comment: And don't just change the error message because it doesn't match reality. You changed `>` to `<` without even bothering to change `gt`. We're trying to help you out, Devil, but you're making it pretty hard by just making stuff up.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you all.. I found my mistake.. I was undefining not on the right place.. Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: Use "while (1) {...}", the "1==1" hurts my eyes.

Comment: I'll have that in mind next time Bill. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

There is absolutely *nothing* wrong with that code that you initially posted. Nor the code that you replaced it with (other than the annoying infinite loop).

It gets no errors or warnings and, when I change the initialisation to `"9"`, it outputs the string.

In fact, given that your error message is complaining about `>` and there's no such symbol *anywhere* in your code, you have a serious mismatch between reality and your presentation of it.

Seriously, put together the minimal complete code sample that generates the error and post that. Helping people over the net is hard enough without being hobbled by fiction :-)

Comment: With me there is a problem because this code is meant to run in a daemon. I can't post exactly the code as it connects to a database and there is some logic that depends on the results from the database. Basically the code that I posted seems to be working fine as a standalone but it doesn't work when I'm using it in the daemon (Proc::Daemon->new).

Comment: Well, I can only suggest that you post the first 110 lines of your perl program, after sanitising any sensitive information it may contain. But don't take out any more than absolutely necessary and don't remove or add lines, since line 101 will no longer make sense.